# How to bind data that come from database into angular dynamic form dropdown?

Tags: json, angular, database, typescript

I am creating Angular7 dynamic form and this form contains a dropdown. This dropdown has **options** property. I want to populate this property from the database. But in the official Angular Dynamic Form document, values insert into options property while inputs are being created.

I tried this one:

```
this.formComponent.form.controls['currencyId'].patchValue([{value: '076398a7-ea74-431c-9c63-121af6fe0f2f', label: 'deneme'}]);
```

```
new InputDropdown({
  key: 'parentJobDepartmentId',
  label: '...',
  options: [],
  value: '...',
  required: false,
  order: 2
})
```

I am using ng-select library for dropdown.

```
<ng-select [ngClass]="'ng-select'" [options]="input.options" [formControlName]="input.key" [id]="input.key" (change)="input.onChange($event.target.value)"></ng-select>
```

I need to populate InputDropdown.options property dynamically(from the database.).

How can I do that?
Could you help me with this problem?

Comment: can you post `html` code

Comment: I updated code and added ```html``` ram12393.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how bind data came from database into dropdowns.

If you call data that you need in `ngOnInit`, then you are letting data that captured before UI codes.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getJobDepartments();
  }
```

When you call UI code in `ngAfterViewInit` then you can make sure that first, you get data then the UI.

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.inputs = this.getInputs();
  }
```

And you can use data in dropdown like below.

```
new InputDropdown({
  key: 'parentJobDepartmentId',
  label: '...',
  options: this.jobDepartments,
  value: '...',
  required: false,
  order: 2
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't looking to continuously update these values from the DB then i would suggest building your form up in stages and only assigning the options to the form component once ready.

You could use `forkJoin` for this.

```
forkJoin(this.part1(), this.part2()).subscribe(
   next: value => {
       form_fields = value.flat(1)
   }
   complete: () => {
       // You can sort here as well to keep correct ordering
       form_fields.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
       this.options = form_fields;
    }
)
```

Then pass `[options]="options" to your component and wrap component in *ngIf="questions" then it will hold until ready.

This is probably not the ideal solution but its how i have tackled it in the past. Hope it helps.

Comment: No, I will assign once. But I don't understand this code block. Could you explain @Sam?

Comment: Sure, so this.part1 and this.part2 are just functions in which you build up your form. Lets say part1 is all your text inputs date inputs dropdowns with non server fetched values, and then part2 is where you define your server fetched values. Each one is just returning an array of options to pass to your dynamic form component. So you end up with [{options}] [{options}] which gets merged into one with flat(1) [{options}, {options}]. Then you can assign this all at once to the form component and you won't run into the issue of the form being created in front of you receiving server response.

Comment: I tried to implement it but I didn't understand. I need a simpler solution. Thank you.

Comment: Fair enough, i suppose one very simple solution would be to set a boolean flag to true when you receive the data back from the server, then you could `ngIf="flag"` on the dynamic form component. This should prevent it rendering until you have the data.

Comment: Make sense. I will try it.